# Python 3, eval, SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python-3.x, eval

I'm testing a code example but keep getting an error

```
# interactive updates
import shelve
from person import Person
fieldnames = ('name', 'age', 'job', 'pay')

db = shelve.open('class-shelve')
while True:
    key = input('\nKey? => ')
    if not key: break
    if key in db:
        record = db[key]                      # update existing record
    else:                                     # or make/store new rec
        record = Person(name='?', age='?')    # eval: quote strings
    for field in fieldnames:
        currval = getattr(record, field)
        newtext = input('\t[%s]=%s\n\t\tnew?=>' % (field, currval))
        if newtext:
            #print('Blah Blah' + newtext)
            setattr(record, field, eval(newtext))
            #setattr(record, field, 'Testing')
        db[key] = record
db.close()
```

I get this error when trying to update a record using the setattr when eval function is used.

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Problem seem to be the eval part, I'm aware of the security issue with eval, but here I'm trying to get an example working.
Class Person is very simple with 4 fields for storing the values.

Comment: Can you add what is the error?

Comment: In what line is the EOF? Can I get the full traceback? (Full error)

Comment: I added the error message:
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Key? => ulrik
        [name]=Ulrik Hjarnaa
                new?=>Ulrik Hjarnaa2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peopleinteract_update.py", line 41, in <module>
    setattr(record, field, eval(newtext))
  File "<string>", line 1
    Ulrik Hjarnaa2

Comment: Why are you calling eval, and what do you expect eval to do here? This is the prototypical example of where you should never use eval, btw

Comment: The example (from a Python book, Programming Python, O'Reilly, 4th edition)), what I think the example tries is to get Python to cast the different input to different formats, name to string, age and pay to int, job to string

Comment: I tried to understand why the error occurs, is there a change in Python, since the example (which is created for Python 3), doesn't work? Or a setting I need to handle.

Comment: Yes, well `eval` simply evaluates a string as python source code using the python interpreter. If you wrote `Ulrik Hjarnaa` in a file `myfile.py` and did `python myfile.py`  or simply wrote `>>> Ulrik Hjarnaa` in a REPL session you would get a syntax error. If you wanted to write a string literal, you'd need `"Ulrik Hjarnaa"` with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You must **quote** string inputs explicitly, as it is written in the book.

ex: new?=>'lucas'